# A Transformation that maps a probability distribution onto another

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions

I am trying to find if there exists a transformation (just a mapping) $T$ in **closed form expressions** that maps the probability distribution
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{\theta}\left[1-\frac{x}{\theta}\right]& \text{for } 0\le x\le \theta \\
 0 & \text{for } x>\theta
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray*}
onto the probability distribution $$g(x) = \frac{1}{\theta}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}.$$
I tried if exponential mapping would work, but unsuccessful. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $f(\frac{2}{\theta}\left[1-\frac{x}{\theta}\right]) = \frac{1}{\theta}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$ so put $\frac{2}{\theta}\left[1-\frac{x}{\theta}\right]=y$ and solve for $-\frac{x}{\theta}$ in terms of y to get $f(y)=\frac{1}{\theta}e^{(\frac{y\theta}{2}-1)}$

Comment: @Paul: Thanks, but $g$ is defined for $x>0$ and the transformation doesn't hold in the interval $x\ge \theta$.